# Limit orders to one product in WooCommerce allowing different variations of a variable product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I try to limit customers buy one product with woocommerce. I use this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart' );
function woo_custom_add_to_cart( $cart_item_data ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

The problem is that I can´t use two variations in the same variable product. I need something to limit one product per order but can allow customer to and multiple variations of the same variable product.

Example: Customer buy a samsung j7 smartphone in color Black and at the same time a samsung j7 in color blue. Now if customer want additionally to add a Sony Xperia smartphone he must do another order for it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will restrict add to cart to allow only item from the same product *(so for variable products, it will allow adding to cart different variations of the same variable product)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 4 );
function filter_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = 0 ) {
    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        return $passed;

    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $items_in_cart = [];

    if ( $product && 'variable' !== $product->get_type() ) {
        $passed = false;
    } elseif ( $product && 'variable' === $product->get_type() ) {
        $items_in_cart[$product_id] = $product_id;

        // Loop through cart items
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
            $items_in_cart[$cart_item['product_id']] = $cart_item['product_id'];
        }
        if( count($items_in_cart) > 1 )
            $passed = false;
    }

    // Avoid add to cart and display an error notice
    if( ! $passed )
        wc_add_notice( __("Different items are not allowed on an order.", "woocommerce" ), 'error' );

    return $passed;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.